# Dynamically positioning UILabel to bottom of content view with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, swift3

I was trying to position my dynamically created UILabels to my contentView's bottom. I'm using HTML Parser called Fuzi to catch HTML tags and creating UILabels based on them;

```
func stringFromHTML( _ string: String?)
{
    do{
        let doc = try HTMLDocument(string: string!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        if let root = doc.body {
            for element in root.children {
                if element.tag == "h2" {
                    // Create new label
                    let label = UILabel()
                    label.text = element.stringValue
                    label.numberOfLines = 0
                    label.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir Next", size: 17)
                    label.textColor = UIColor.black
                    self.contentView.addSubview(label)
                    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

                    // Label constraints
                    let labelLeading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)
                    let labelTrailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -20)
                    let labelTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: self.contentView.frame.origin.y)

                    self.contentView.addConstraints([labelLeading, labelTrailing, labelTop])

                }
                updateContentViewHeight()
            }
        }

    } 
    catch{
        print("html error\n",error)
    }

}

func updateContentViewHeight(){
    var totalContentHeight:CGFloat = 0.0
    for i in self.contentView.subviews {
        totalContentHeight += i.frame.height
    }
    let contentViewHeight:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: totalContentHeight-29)
    self.contentView.addConstraint(contentViewHeight)

}
```

I tried calling my stringFromHTML function in viewDidAppear. But it positions my UILabels to far far away (they don't seem).

I want to position my labels to the bottom of the last label, see the image below;

[image: My screen...]

Anyone can help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to add labels on ladders style i.e. the later on top of the former?

Comment: @Adeel I want to add labels to the bottom of the content each time the loop executes. For e.g. in my HTML there are <h2>'s and <p>'s, I'll create a label for each of them and align them one by one...

Comment: I get it that you want to add a label every time you encounter a an `h2` or a `p` tag. But I'm asking you about the arrangement/alignment of these labels. Do you wan to lay them horizontally or vertically? It would be helpful if you could provide a screenshot of what you want.

Comment: @Adeel vertically :)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
let labelTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: self.contentView.frame.origin.y)
```

To

```
if label != nil {
let labelTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: label[index], attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 2)
} else {
let labelTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: self.contentView.frame.origin.y)
}
```

Because you are basically forcing each label to be at the same y position.

Comment: Can I ask an image of how your problem looks like?